# Rackspace hardware acceleration

Tags: windows-server-2008, drivers, rackspace, graphics, hardware-acceleration

I am using a Windows Server 2008 on Rackspace and I need to use some of its Direct3D capabilities (for Microsoft Office extra functionality).

However, I can't because the system reports that I only have a 'Standard VGA adapter' installed.

How should I go about it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a VPS or dedicated server? It is possible that the server has no 3D capable adapter installed.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen It's a VPS...

Answer (score 1):

Generally VPS servers don't have 3D capabilities. You have to get a real server and make sure the graphics adapter for it can handle 3D.

Comment: I just need to do something like this: https://blogs.vmware.com/smb/2012/10/mouse-performance.html#more-771 but on rackspace. Plus there is also another server on Microsoft Azure which has acceleration enabled by default.

Comment: You should ask Rackspace if what Hypervisor technology they use, and if there are Windows graphics drivers available for it.

Answer (score 1):

If your server is a physical one then you'll need a specific type of GPU to achieve what you're looking for, specifically an NVidia Grid GPU. This is a PCIe card that provides virtual GPUs to applications running in environments such as Citrix or VMWare/View.

[Here](http://www.nvidia.co.uk/object/grid-vdi-graphics-cards-uk.html)'s a link.